# Any ways to short-up such chain call?

Tags: javascript

Is there any ways to short-up such chain call?

```
if (obj && obj.prop && obj.prop.subProp1 && obj.prop.subProp1.subPropFunc) {
    obj.prop.subProp1.subPropFunc();
}
```

The only alternative I can imagine is `try-catch`. Any other ideas?
*I really tired of writing these. It's much easier in [coffeescript](/questions/tagged/coffeescript) using `?.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work given your sample code (haven't tested "all cases", just a copy of your sample):

```
function propsExist(obj) {
    if (!obj) return false;
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (!obj[arguments[i]]) return false;
        obj = obj[arguments[i]];
    }
    return true;
}

if (propsExist(obj, "prop", "subProp1", "subPropFunc")) {
    obj.prop.subProp1.subPropFunc();
}
```

The method `propsExist()` takes a variable number of arguments, the first of which being the original object you want to check properties/functions on. It will iterate through the list of properties you send to it and check them in-order. If one doesn't exist, it will return `false`. If it makes it through the whole loop, it validated successfully!

If you *always* want to call the sub-property's function if it validates, you could also just change the `propsExist` function to call it instead of returning true (then rename the function to something like `callIfValid(obj, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as the previous post, just a different solution.

```
function checkChain(variablePath,startingPoint){
    var check = startingPoint || window,
        parts =  variablePath.split("."),
        i;

    for (i=0;i<parts.length;i++) {
        check = check[parts[i]];
        if (!check) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return check;
}

var foo = { bar : { cat : { says : function(x){ alert(x); } } } };

var test1 = checkChain("foo.bar.cat.says");
if (test1) {
    test1("meow");
}

var test2 = checkChain("foo.bar.cat.bark");
if (test2) {
    test2("burp");
}

var test3 = checkChain("cat.says",foo.bar);
if (test3) {
    test3("huh?");
}
```